# Can I enable Login when I can't connect to the instance?

Tags: sql-server, logins

I have a cloned a customer machine to a Virtual machine.
I had access from my code (`SqlConnection`) to the database through a database-Login where I could use window autentication.

I disabled my Login(I though I could enable it again).

Is there any way to enable the Login?

The solutions I found where you `Grant` something, all require that you are connected to the instance, but it's also not possible to connect without first a login.

If I had the `sa` pwd I would be able to login, but I don't know that either.

Is there any other way, I can enable my Login?

Comment: If resetting the `sa` password is an option, my preferred option (of the many available on that linked possible dupe) is https://docs.dbatools.io/#Reset-DbaAdmin

Comment: It's the "Pc123\Administrator" in the "Security\Logins" I have disable, so is it possible to follow that guide, when it used the "Windows Administrator account"?

Comment: I guess if I have any chance of enableling the Administrator Login, it must be through resetting the sa pwd.

Comment: if mixed mode auth is not enabled, you can try [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out). if you encounter more specific errors you're not able to overcome, I encourage you to edit this post to include that information or ask a new question relevant to the specific errors